# Unable to load the public file HTTP ERROR 500 in new Laravel project

Tags: laravel

[image: when i do localhost:8888/itc this is what i get]

i want it to load welcome.blade.php directly

When I try to load my public file localhost:8888/itc/public

This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

Comment: Which server? Nothing in your Laravel logs? Why is `public` in your URL?

Comment: @kerbholz am using mamp server

Comment: @kerbholz how do i make my localhost:8888/itc load my welcome.blade.php directly

Comment: Have you tried http://localhost:8888? You can't directly load blade files - Laravel serves them up for you. What routes do you have defined?

Comment: @NicolasGoosen i have the home route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel you should set the public directory of your project as the document root of the webserver.

You have to change the default document root from `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` to `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/itc/public`.

After changing it, restart the servers and visit: `localhost:8888`

Check out the [documentation page of MAMP](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Mac/Preferences/Web-Server/)